# OpenLdap ForWindows how to check if search is using an index - and if it's not - why not?

Tags: indexing, openldap

I have some "groupOfNames" with users listed in the member attribute.

My search filter is:

```
(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=uid=test23564,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com)
```

And my index definition is: (oldDbIndex)

```
member eq
```

I loaded up about 30,000 users across 5 groups.

First with no index and the search took about 3 seconds.

I then completely cleared the data, created the index and then loaded the data again (had probs getting slapindex to work!!)

The search still took about 3 seconds - so it appears to not be using the index.

So, 2 questions, is there a kind of explain plan for openldap?  And how can I speed up this query?????

Comment: You didn't need to reload after creating the index. You'll probably have to run slapd with a -d value and interpret the log output. The 'problems getting slapindex to work' might be interesting to hear about. Does the index file timestamp indicate that it got updated during the reload?

Comment: @EJP There is a `member.bdb` file in the OpenLDAP/data directory and yes, it grows as the data was loaded (and timestamp as well)

Comment: Sounds good. Looks like you're stuck with the debug output. The various levels are documented somewhere. It does print out whether it's using an index, I've seen that.

Comment: I thought I'd try using groupOfUniqueNames and uniqueMember eq for the index, but now when I'm loading it's not updating the uniqueMember.bdb file at all... :(

Comment: @EJP does it also print out if it DOESN'T use an index?

Comment: sorry, I was incorrect, the index files are NOT being updated. (the timestamps of all the files get updated when you stop the service)

Comment: actually, it looks like none of the indexes are being updated.  And if I query using cn=<cn> it takes just as long as my other search (3 seconds).  So it looks like my setup isn't indexing at all

Comment: *sigh* I've removed my index and doing a load now, and the other indexes ARE now being updated.

Comment: I can't post an answer yet so adding a comment - I have some sort of solution.  

I changed the base dn to only look at the groups as previously it was scanning the entire tree including all the users and it now returns instantly.

I'm still a little concerned at the potential scalability (my test has 30,000 users and 5 groups) as it still has to scan through 6,000 member attributes for each group.

Comment: If you have indexes it will use them. Put the index specification back, stop slapd, run slaptest, fix whatever it tells you to fix, run slapindex, check that the index exists and has a decent size, run slapd, retest. As I said above, you don't have to reload.